# Git - new branch and remote tracking (configure for push/pull with origin/master)

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-remote

What does `Track Remote Branch` do? Also what does it mean `configure for push/pull with origin/master`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tracking a remote branch means you want to automatically merge changes from the remote branch you’re tracking into your local branch. The [default behavior of `git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-codegitpushorigincode) pushes changes into a configured upstream only when the names of the local and remote are the same. In your case, you would not modify `origin/master` with a push to `feature1`.

For a feature branch where you’re collaborating with others, you generally want to track, say, `origin/feature1` rather than `origin/master`. If you are working a feature solo, you may not want to set up tracking at all.

The [`git branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--t) describes what happens under the hood to set up tracking.

> When creating a new branch, set up `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` configuration entries to mark the start-point branch as "upstream" from the new branch. This configuration will tell git to show the relationship between the two branches in `git status` and `git branch -v`. Furthermore, it directs `git pull` without arguments to pull from the upstream when the new branch is checked out.

The same section continues

> This behavior is the default when the start point is a remote-tracking branch.

A remote-tracking branch (or just tracking branch for short) has a names of the form `remote/branch-name`. A git repository typically has a branch named `master`, so a clone will almost always have a local `master` branch and a tracking branch named `origin/master`. Think of `origin/master` as marking the point in history where the `master` branch was on your `origin` remote at the time of your most recent `git pull` or `git fetch`.

Answer (score 3):

**Example Scenario:**

Suppose you have 1 remote `master` branch on Azure and 1 local `master` branch on your PC
[image]

On you local PC
[image]
Now
[image]

After commiting changes on `masterA` and `masterB` and pushing changes to remote repository your branches will apper like this on your PC

[image]

and on remote repositry like azure branches will apper like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the docs from [git](https://git-scm.com/):

> A 'tracking branch' in Git is a local branch that is connected to a remote branch. When you push and pull on that branch, it automatically pushes and pulls to the remote branch that it is connected with.
>
> Use this if you always pull from the same upstream branch into the new branch, and if you don't want to use "git pull" explicitly.

If you track your local branches to your remote ones, ie `feature1` tracks `origin/feature1` and the same for `master`, then you are safe!

**Edit**: Here is a great [explanation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches) form the ProGit book. Basically:

> Tracking branches are local branches that have a direct relationship to a remote branch. If you’re on a tracking branch and type git pull, Git automatically knows which server to fetch from and which branch to merge in.